# Selecionar um trecho de código xml com regex

Tags: regex

Preciso de uma ajuda novamente com Regex!
Preciso editar um arquivo xml e inserir após uma determinada informação uma sequência de instruções. Porém não consigo selecionar toda a informação que necessito. Preciso selecionar a seguinte informação:

```
    <testerconfirmation title="Tester Confirmation " passedbutton="yes" timeoutresult="failed">REQUIREMENT SPECTED
After T_Checkdisplay (5 seconds), the indication OIL CHANGE REQUEST V3 must be activated according to indications characteristics during 5 seconds.

Press YES to continue.</testerconfirmation>
```

No caso a cima preciso selecionar toda a informação que esteja dentro da tag  e contém a informação  OIL CHANGE REQUEST V3. Após encontrar esta informação preciso inserir algumas linhas de código depois da informação selecionada.
Estas são as linhas que quero adicionar:

```
<capltestfunction title="RUN INSPECTION" name="RunInspection">
<caplparam type="string" name="InspName" />
</capltestfunction>
<capltestfunction title="ADD IMAGE TO REPORT" name="AddInspectionImageToReport" />
<capltestfunction title="CHECK ST_F-4" name="CheckStepResultCamera">
<caplparam type="string" name="StepName">ST_F-4</caplparam>
<caplparam type="float" name="ExpVal">1</caplparam>
<caplparam type="float" name="ToleranceUnits" />
<caplparam type="float" name="TolerancePercent" />
</capltestfunction>
<capltestfunction title="CHECK ICON_F-4" name="CheckStepResultCamera">
<caplparam type="string" name="StepName">ICON_F-4</caplparam>
<caplparam type="float" name="ExpVal">1</caplparam>
<caplparam type="float" name="ToleranceUnits" />
<caplparam type="float" name="TolerancePercent" />
</capltestfunction>
<capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE PB058_1" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
<caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_PB058_1</caplparam>
<caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">OilChange</caplparam>
<caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
<caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
</capltestfunction>
<capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE PB058_2" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
<caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_PB058_2</caplparam>
<caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">Required</caplparam>
<caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
<caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
</capltestfunction>
```

Então o código da seguinte forma:

```
<testerconfirmation title="Tester Confirmation " passedbutton="yes" timeoutresult="failed">REQUIREMENT SPECTED
After T_Checkdisplay (5 seconds), the indication OIL CHANGE REQUEST V3 must be activated according to indications characteristics during 5 seconds.
Press YES to continue.</testerconfirmation>

  <capltestfunction title="RUN INSPECTION" name="RunInspection">
    <caplparam type="string" name="InspName" />
  </capltestfunction>
  <capltestfunction title="ADD IMAGE TO REPORT" name="AddInspectionImageToReport" />
  <capltestfunction title="CHECK ST_F-4" name="CheckStepResultCamera">
    <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">ST_F-4</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="float" name="ExpVal">1</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="float" name="ToleranceUnits" />
    <caplparam type="float" name="TolerancePercent" />
  </capltestfunction>
  <capltestfunction title="CHECK ICON_F-4" name="CheckStepResultCamera">
    <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">ICON_F-4</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="float" name="ExpVal">1</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="float" name="ToleranceUnits" />
    <caplparam type="float" name="TolerancePercent" />
  </capltestfunction>
  <capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE PB058_1" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
    <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_PB058_1</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">OilChange</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
    <caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
  </capltestfunction>
  <capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE PB058_2" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
    <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_PB058_2</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">Required</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
    <caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
  </capltestfunction>
```

Estou usando o Notepad ++, porém se tiverem alguma solução ou experiência com algum outro Sw que facilite trabalhar com código por favor deixe um comentário que também será bem vindo!
Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Eu não entendi o que você precisa selecionar e o que você precisa substituir...

Comment: Olá @KhaosDoctor , desculpe se não ficou claro a explicação. Na verdade preciso encontrar a primeira parte do código(<testerconfirmation até </testerconfirmation>) e acrescentar depois desta informação a segunda parte do código (que começa em <capltestfunction title="RUN INSPECTION" name="RunInspection">). Espero que tenha ajudado! Obrigado!

Comment: @KhaosDoctor veja se melhorou?

Comment: Olha, eu acredito que [isso](https://regex101.com/r/uSK5Z5/2) vai te ajudar, mas você vai ter que fazer um trabalho manual pegando o grupo todo e substituindo por ele mesmo, **mais** sua nova string na linha de baixo

Comment: @KhaosDoctor, criei este regex (^\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s<testerconfirmation.*\n.*REMOTE START SHUT DOWN V3.*\n.*\n.*<\/testerconfirmation>) para selecionar a informação que preciso, porém quando vou substituir repedindo a informação selecionada($1+ o resto do text) ele não substitui corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar isso

```
( *<testerconfirmation(.|\n)*?(?=<\/testerconfirmation>)<\/testerconfirmation>)
```

Bom vou explicar por partes o que cada parte faz.

```
 *<testerconfirmation
```

Essa regex captura todos os caracteres de espaço que tenham a sequencia `<testerconfirmation` após elas e a sequencia`<testerconfirmation`

```
(.|\n)*?
```

Essa parte captura todos os caracteres (incluindo os especiais) de forma lazy (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
(?=<\/testerconfirmation>)
```

Um positive lookahead para capturar até o trecho <\testerconfirmation>

```
<\/testerconfirmation>
```

Uma parte para capturar </testerconfirmation>, pois o positive lookahead só determina onde a sequencia de captura deve parar.

Quanto a adicionar aquela sequencia de código, sugiro que use alguma aplicaçãozinha bem simples no VS, como usar a regex para varrer o código, pegar todas as ocorrencias e concatenar a sequencia de texto que você descreveu aqui a cada uma delas.